# Conceptually Understand Quick Sort

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to visualize Quick Sort working. Mainly, I am trying to understand the partition portion to it. I will post the code below:

```
public int paritionIt(int left, int right, long pivot){
    leftPtr = left - 1;
    rightPtr = right + 1;

    while (true) {
        while (leftPtr < right && Array[++leftPtr] < pivot);
        while (rightPtr > left && Array[--rightPtr] > pivot);
        if (leftPtr <= rightPtr)
            break;
        else
            swap(leftPtr, rightPtr);
    } //end while loop
    return leftPtr;
}
```

My ultimate question is: Why do we return the leftPtr? I feel like this wouldn't be right... The Quick sort algorithm uses recursion like so:

```
public void recQuicksort(int left, int right){
    if(left - right <= 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        long pivot = array[right];
        int partition = partitionIt(left, right, pivot);
        recQuicksort(left, partition -1);
        recQuicksort(partition + 1, right);
    }
}
```

I am just having a difficult time trying to conceptualize this.

Comment: Please format your code...

Comment: You're leaving out some code.  Who calls `partitionIt`?

Comment: if you want to "visualize" what is happening, try to use the debugger from your preferred IDE. It can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to visualize what is happening on paper before I begin to put it into an IDE, I feel I learn better this way.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/52233/slides/QuickSort1x1.pdf) visual enough?

Comment: [Actually there are many of them in the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=quicksort+diagram&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS530US530&oq=quicks&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0j69i59j0l3.10372j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) Take your pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job of this particular version of partition is to reorder the list so that all elements no greater than the pivot appear before all elements no less than the pivot. (This means that elements equal to the pivot can be scattered anywhere. Also it must return the index of the start of the second sub-list.

Many orderings can meet this requirement.  For one ordering, more than one return value may be valid. This doesn't interfere with the proper operation of Quicksort, so no worries.

For your example data (3,9,4,7), the first pass will stop with left=1, right=3 and so it will swap 7 and 9 to produce (3,7,4,9).  Next it will stop with left = 3 and right = 2, which causes a break from the other loop.  The returned value is 3.  This is correct because it's *one step past* the end of the initial subarray that is now entirely less than or equal to the pivot.

However with this version of partition, the quicksort has a bug.  It should be:

```
public void recQuicksort(int left, int right) {
  if (left < right) {
    long pivot = array[right];
    int partition = partitionIt(left, right, pivot);
    recQuicksort(left, partition - 1);
    recQuicksort(partition, right);
  }
}
```

Comment: But won't the partition ultimately return some random value? Meaning, if i had 4 elements in the array (3,9,4,7), it would return 4? or 9? You've done a great job at explaining it by the way.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast note that I changed my answer.  This version of partition works differently from the one I knew.  It isn't buggy as I initially thought.

Comment: I appreciate the help. This makes much more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I developed a web page to visualize the process of quicksort, current version support last item as pivot, I think the page will help you understand quicksort.[quick sort](http://ds.fufanfan.com/quick_sort/)

To show how quick sort work on data set (1,2,3,4,5), you just type **1 2 3 4 5** and press enter.To show best case ,please input **b5** , the digit **5** means the recusive depth.To show average case, please input **r1..10**, **r** means **random**, **1..10** means random permutation data set of **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10**.

Here is a best case example:
[image]

worst case:

[image]

average case:

[image]